# C# Save location of drawn Ellipse in List<Point>?

Tags: c#, list, point, onpaint

a small question here where I didn't find a proper answer to.
I want to save a drawn location of a Ellipse so I can later on draw a line between 2 ellipses, so I want to save this as a point if this is possible.

```
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        screen.Clear(Color.Black);

        using (var p = new Pen(Color.White, 2))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < p1List.Count; x++)
            {
                screen.DrawLine(p, p1List[x], p2List[x]);
            }
        }

        List<Point> punten = new List<Point>();


        foreach (var pair in this.droppedShapes)
        {
            var shapeType = pair.Item2; // Reveal your own shape object here
            var location = pair.Item1;


            switch (shapeType) // Reveal your own shape object here
            {
                case 0:
                    screen.DrawRectangle(whitePen, location.X - 10, location.Y - 10, 40, 40);
                    screen.DrawString("&", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, (float)28), whiteBrush, location.X - 11, location.Y - 13);
                    //input       
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 25, location.Y, location.X - 10, location.Y );
                    screen.FillEllipse(greenBrush, location.X - 30, location.Y - 5, 10, 10);
                    punten.Add(); //add the location of the "ellipse"
                    //input       
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X - 25, location.Y + 20, location.X - 10, location.Y + 20);
                    screen.FillEllipse(greenBrush, location.X - 30, location.Y + 15, 10, 10);

                    //output      
                    screen.DrawLine(whitePen, location.X + 30, location.Y + 10, location.X + 45, location.Y + 10);
                    screen.FillEllipse(greenBrush, location.X + 40, location.Y + 5, 10, 10);
```

I already added the line "punten.Add()" because this is the line where I want to save the location. 
If there is a better way, hit me up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems alright to me, just replace your

```
punten.Add();
```

with

```
punten.Add(new Point(location.X, location.Y));
```

or something similar for drawing the lines between the locations. 
Be aware that this will only add Points to your list, if the case 0 in the switch statement is hit, otherwise your List may not contain any Points (or you add Points to the list in the other case sections).

Comment: Thank you! I think this will do :)